# how to access indexedb using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using frisbyjs to fetch live data from couchdb and now I need to verify saved data in indexeddb by the application. Is there a away to access indexeddb using protractor?

Answer (score 3):

You can access anything on the client with `executeScript`.

```
  //protrator.conf.js
  onPrepare: function () {
    global.getFromLocalStorage = function (key) {
      return browser.executeScript(function (key) {
        return localStorage.get(key);
      }, key);
    };
```

Then, use that in your tests:

```
//user-spec.js
it('should save user to localstorage', function () {
  expect(getFromLocalStorage('user-profile').name).to.Contain('Jorge');
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Now, if there is no sync access to storage (like in IndexedDB), you'd want to use executeAsyncScript instead:

```
  //protrator.conf.js
  onPrepare: function () {
    global.getFromIndexedDB = function (key) {
      return browser.executeAsyncScript(function (key, cb) {
        window.myDB.get(key).onsuccess = function (e) {
          cb(e.target.result);
        }
      }, key);
    };

//user-spec.js
it('should save user to indexeddb properly', function () {
  expect(getFromIndexedDB('user-profile').name).to.Contain('Jorge');
});
```